# Attempt to present whose view is not in window hierarchy ( when using segue ) objective - c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 View Controllers and I get the error above using this:

```
-(void)hitwtf{

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ufo.frame, sanchez.frame)) {
        if(((sanchez.frame.origin.y + sanchez.frame.size.height - 5) <= (ufo.frame.origin.y)) && (sanchezJumping < 0))
        {

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToGameOver" sender:self];
}        
}
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushToGameOver"]){

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sanchezdeath);


    GameOverViewController *controller = (GameOverViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.CurrentScore = CurrentScore;

        }
}
```

It works, the view gets displayed but I am just getting this error. I don't use any buttons, the view should change when two frames hit each other, so I need the performSegueWithIdentifier, don't I?

EDIT:

Answer is :

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   if(timer)
   {
     [timer invalidate];
     timer = nil;
   }
 }
```

Comment: have you tried putting breakpoints in the prepareForSegue method? Maybe it is called multiple times?

Comment: I have added a sound ( see in edited thread ) , and yes it is called multiple times. But how do i stop it? I am removing sanchez in the prepare for segue method swell, so how can the frames still have contact and call the prepareForSegue method again? Or maybe it is the timer cause I call hitwtf every 0.05 seconds?

Comment: Invalidate the timer before performing the segue?

Comment: how do i invalidate a timer?

Comment: invalidating helped, ill add the code to the question , thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have two ideas for your problem (in response to the comments.):

Either move the sanchez / ufo back to the place it was before the collision.

Or add a boolean

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL collision;
```

And add this in your method:

```
if(!self.collision && ((sanchez.frame.origin.y + sanchez.frame.size.height - 5) <= (ufo.frame.origin.y)) && (sanchezJumping < 0))
    {
        self.collision = YES;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToGameOver" sender:self];
```

Comment: the answer was to invalidate the timer , ill edit my post thank you